# I don't catch perfect RGB color on tap in an ImageView

Tags: ios, swift, rgb

I don't catch perfect RGB color on tap in an ImageView in my application with location coordinate. I wrote this:

```
extension UIImage {
func getPixelColors(atLocation location: CGPoint, withFrameSize size: CGSize) -> UIColor {
    let x: CGFloat = (self.size.width) * location.x / size.width
    let y: CGFloat = (self.size.height) * location.y / size.height
    let pixelPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    let pixelData = self.cgImage!.dataProvider!.data
    let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)
    let pixelIndex: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pixelPoint.y)) + Int(pixelPoint.x)) * 4
    let r = CGFloat(data[pixelIndex]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let g = CGFloat(data[pixelIndex+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let b = CGFloat(data[pixelIndex+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let a = CGFloat(data[pixelIndex+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    //let testColor = UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
}
```

I call getPixelColors:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      guard let touch = touches.first else {
 print("Error: touches is empty.")
 return
 }
 let location = touch.location(in: imgTarget)


 let pin = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: location.x - 14, y: location.y - 14, width: 30, height: 30))
 pin.image = UIImage(named: "gMarker")
 imgTarget.addSubview(pin)
 rgb = (imgTarget.image?.getPixelColors(atLocation: location, withFrameSize: imgTarget.frame.size))! }
```

The rgb code is correct if I tap in the central part of the image, 
the further away I get from the center, the more the error increases

Comment: You suppose too many things that are not correct when you are accessing image data using `CFDataGetBytePtr` on the data provider. You cannot be sure the data is in RGBA format. You cannot be sure how long a line is (e.g. there can be padding). And you cannot be sure that the image data starts with the top left corner. I suppose the image data is upside down.

Comment: I created the image by removing any padding whit a graphics software

Comment: It would be easier to add the image to an UIImageView  and implement a UIView color picker

Comment: I found the cause of the problem, 
the tap does not work right and left because of the following assignment in the viewDidLoad:
imgTarget.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill, if I comment this part it works but I have the image not in scale, is there another way to assign this parameter?